# INF problem for Plug&Play ( use IoRegisterPlugPlayNotification )

Tags: windows, winapi, usb, kernel, device-driver

hi want  to  use  IoRegisterPlugPlayNotification for notify when new usb get plug-in  ! my code dont work (i dont get notify)

can use IoRegisterPlugPlayNotification  in DriverEntry? 
without use Adddevice i can get notify ?
i must use INF file to get notification ? why ?

what GUID i must use ? in code and INF file?

```
NTSTATUS DriverEntry(IN PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject, IN PUNICODE_STRING  RegistryPath)
  {

NTSTATUS status;
int i;

//{a5dcbf10-6530-11d2-901f-00c04fb951ed}
DriverObject->DriverUnload=usblockerUnload;

for (i=0;i<IRP_MJ_MAXIMUM_FUNCTION;i++)
    DriverObject->MajorFunction[i] = Driver_PNP;
DriverObject->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_PNP] = Driver_PNP;



status=IoRegisterPlugPlayNotification( EventCategoryDeviceInterfaceChange,
    PNPNOTIFY_DEVICE_INTERFACE_INCLUDE_EXISTING_INTERFACES, 
    (PVOID)&GUID_CLASS_USB_DEVICE,
    DriverObject, 
    (PDRIVER_NOTIFICATION_CALLBACK_ROUTINE)PnpNotifyInterfaceChange, 
    (PVOID)DriverObject, 
    &NotificationHandle);


if(!NT_SUCCESS(status))
{
    DbgPrint("error in IoRegisterPlugPlayNotification  \n");

    return status;
}


DbgPrint("  Driver Entry oK ***   \n");

return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}

 void usblockerUnload(IN PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject)
  {
NTSTATUS    status;
DbgPrint(" Unload   \r");

status=IoUnregisterPlugPlayNotification(NotificationHandle);
if(!NT_SUCCESS(status))
{
    DbgPrint("error in IoUnregisterPlugPlayNotification \n");


}
    }

    #pragma PAGEDCODE
       NTSTATUS  PnpNotifyInterfaceChange( PVOID pNotifyContext, PVOID pContext ) 
    { 
PDEVICE_INTERFACE_CHANGE_NOTIFICATION pNotifyData =      (PDEVICE_INTERFACE_CHANGE_NOTIFICATION)pNotifyContext; 


    DbgPrint("symbolic name: %wZ\n", pNotifyData->SymbolicLinkName);
    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
         }
```

Comment: What is the problem? Do you receive the notifications? Also, you might want to use the non-obsolete GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE, though technically it's the same.

In the callback, you could definitely call IoSetDeviceInterfaceState on the received DEVICE_INTERFACE_CHANGE_NOTIFICATION.SymbolicLinkName, though I'm not sure how nice it'd be to the symlink's real owner.

Comment: i dont receive notifications  , my driver must be PNP? i must implement Adddevice? and i must use INF file?

Comment: No, it doesn't have to be PnP. If it's not PnP, make sure you install it properly and start the service. Typically it's done with an INF file. I don't know why you'd want to do it manually - INF is the simplest way.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to write a NT-style driver (a.k.a. legacy driver). You don't **need** to install it with an .INF file; just have it installed as a service and `net start yourdriver` (or set its start-up as Automatic in the service properties).

As a side note: Make sure you actually understand what you're doing. You seem to have subjects mixed up. For example, an NT-style driver does not handle IRP_MJ_PNPs -- it simply never receives them. You still can register for PnP notifications, of course: you'll receive them in a callback function, but it has nothing to do with IRP_MJ_PNP.